# How to avoid "Result set too large to be sorted" in TDengine?

Tags: database

I created a table "test_result" in TDengine database. It is used to store the IoT sensor data by time. I want to sort the data, but encountered an error:

```
taos> select * from test_result order by ts desc limit 5;
DB error: Result set too large to be sorted(0.292303s)
taos>
```

Is there any configuration to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

you can modify maxNumOfOrderedRes to allow more results.
the default value  is 10000 , and the max is 1000000.